# Identity-Based Encryption consist of four algorithms. Extract phase is one of them and it is done by PKG or receiver?

Tags: identity-based-encryption

The Identity-Based Encryption consist of four randomized algorithms: Setup, Extract, Encrypt, Decryption. The Setup phase is done by Private-key generator, Encrypt by sender and Decryption by receiver. the Extract phase is done by PKG or receiver?

Answer (score 2):

The Extract phase is performed by the *Private Key Generator* (PKG). Note that in IBE it is not necessary a Public Key Generator, since public keys are just arbitrary bit strings or "identities". So, to sum up:

- Setup, executed by the PKG. This algorithm creates, among other things, a master key for the PKG.
- Extract, executed by the PKG. This algorithm enables the creation of the corresponding private key for an arbitrary identity. The PKG needs the master key for doing this.
- Encrypt, executed by the sender, who only needs to specify the receivers' identity.
- Decrypt, executed by the receiver, who is in possession of a private key that must be generated by the Extract algorithm.

This is much better explained in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_encryption#Protocol_framework).

Comment: Are you saying that in IBE, PKG is not necessary.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "PKG". In your question you said "*Public* Key Generator", which is not necessary in IBE, since public keys are just arbitrary bit strings. However, you do need a "*Private* Key Generator", in order to compute the private key associated to an arbitrary bit string.